# How do logical && and || operators along with increment and decrement work?

Tags: c, logical-operators, pre-increment

Evaluate the following expressions. Find `x,y,z` values in each case. Assuming `x=1` and `y=5` initially, what do you observe:

1. `z=++x && ++y;`
2. `z=--x && --y;`
3. `z=++x || ++y;`
4. `z=--x || --y;`

How are logical operators affecting the values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe "what do you observe" is very explicit in that you should *see* something. That almost certainly means writing the code and examining what happens.

In any case, the logical operators treat `0` as false, anything else as true. The *output* of those operators is `0` for false and `1` for true.

Also keep in mind that the pre-increment and -decrement operators change the value *before* use.

And, finally, be aware that `&&` and `||` are short-circuiting operators which means the second sub-expression may not always be evaluated. For example:

```
int x = 1 ; int y = 5 ; int z = --x && --y;
```

will leave `y` equal to 5, because the `--x` is zero/false so we know that the whole expression will be false - there's no need to evaluate the second sub-expression.

That should be enough to figure out what the results are, based on your pre-conditions for `x` and `y`.

---

As a hint, let's look at the first one. `++x` and `++y` will be `2` and `6` respectively so both true. Hence `true && true` will give true, ending up as `1`.

---

And now, since you *have* written some code (as per your comment asking about what you considered strange behaviour of the `--` and `++` operators in some cases), here's my sample code which shows the operations:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int x, y, z;

    x = 1; y = 5; printf("oldx = %d, oldy= %d", x, y);
    z=++x && ++y;
    printf(", newx= %d, newy = %d, z = %d\n", x, y, z);

    x = 1; y = 5; printf("oldx = %d, oldy= %d", x, y);
    z=--x && --y;
    printf(", newx= %d, newy = %d, z = %d\n", x, y, z);

    x = 1; y = 5; printf("oldx = %d, oldy= %d", x, y);
    z=++x || ++y;
    printf(", newx= %d, newy = %d, z = %d\n", x, y, z);

    x = 1; y = 5; printf("oldx = %d, oldy= %d", x, y);
    z=--x || --y;
    printf(", newx= %d, newy = %d, z = %d\n", x, y, z);

   return 0;
}
```

The output of that is:

```
oldx = 1, oldy= 5, newx= 2, newy = 6, z = 1
oldx = 1, oldy= 5, newx= 0, newy = 5, z = 0
oldx = 1, oldy= 5, newx= 2, newy = 5, z = 1
oldx = 1, oldy= 5, newx= 0, newy = 4, z = 1
```

Comment: Ok I am getting the three cases correct on console  but on executing 2nd case output is d=0,x=0 and y=5 so then why y is not decrementing(pre-decrement)?

Comment: @Mayank, the `&&` operator is short-circuiting. In other words, if the first subexpression is false (it is, since `--x`, when x is one, gives zero), it doe's not evaluate the second subexpression at all. There's no need since `false && ANYTHING` is `false`. That should also be the case for item 3 as well. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your nice explanation. I got it.